# Match cells in different files and return Value of another

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, vlookup

I have two files I need to look up cells in and make sure they match and return the actual value of another. When I use the formula posted below it just returns a True or False and I need the actual value of the cell...

> =IF(V:V='[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,AND(K:K='[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct
>   (2).xls]Inbound'!$X:$X,VLOOKUP('[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct
>   (2).xls]Inbound'!$U:$U,1,0)))

Comment: Is the data in the two sheets arranged in exactly the same order (i.e. will V1 correspond with '[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!W1; V2 with W2, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your formula, nearly each function and bracket in it is wrongly used. Excuse me :-) The `AND` is on the false position, the `IF` has no useful parameters and the `VLOOKUP` makes no sense at all. Try using this formula:

```
=IF(AND(V:V='[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,K:K='[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$X:$X),"success","failed"))
```

I'm not sure if it is correct as I don't have the means to test it here but I tried to resolve your brackets.

As I don't understand at all which value you intend to return from your formula, I return "success" if the row matches succeed and "failed" if not. If that works, replace these string by your desired values.

Comment: I need to compare the P/N in Column V on the import file with the Item in column W on the inbound file and do the same with the QTY in column K on the import file with the qty in column X of inbound file... Only if both columns match I need it to return the value from Column U of the inbound file to column H of the import file...

Comment: The formula - if it is correct - should check if both columns are matching. Maybe first you should check if it works so far by putting it into a cell and look at the result. If there is no success, this problem has to be fixed first.

Comment: OK. I pasted it and it does return a value but its not the correct one for example in both files there is a PN/Item that is the same and the QTY also matches and returns a "failed" outcome when it should be success as both numbers match...

Comment: At this point it is not possible to find the problem as I can't see the data. I suggest that you try to get this condition check working by breaking down the formula to check only one column or even just one cell. Basically you have to understand how these formulas work.

Answer (score 0):

Your OP "I have two files I need to look up cells in and make sure they match"

So looking at the first test in your formula, presumably entered in column H of the sheet where your data being tested sits:

```
V:V='[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W
```

this will return `TRUE` if `V1 = '[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!W1` but `FALSE` if V1 is in any other row of `'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W`

Comparison of columns implicitly tests for equality in the row in which the formula is entered. I prefer to be explicit wherever possible.

It's possible to determine if your PN/Item in column V exists anywhere in `'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W` using one of the lookup functions `VLOOKUP` or `MATCH`. For example:

`= MATCH(V1, '[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,0)`

will return the row number of the first match for V1 in `'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W` even if the searched array is unsorted. It will return a `#N/A` error if no match is found. You need to test firstly if V1 is in the searched array:

`IF(ISNA(MATCH(V1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,0), FALSE, TRUE)`

The reason I return `FALSE` if the match is not found is to allow testing of two conditions within an `AND` function:

`=AND(IF(ISNA(MATCH(V1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,0), FALSE, TRUE), IF(ISNA(MATCH(K1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$X:$X,0), FALSE, TRUE)`
which will evaluate to `AND(TRUE, TRUE)` only if your PN/Item and QTY are found.

At this point all you know is that both values are found but you don't know if they are on the same row so you need another test for that, bearing in mind that `MATCH` returns the position of the matched value within the array being tested:

`=(MATCH(V1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,0) = 
MATCH(K1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$X:$X,0)`

will return `TRUE` if PN/Item and QTY
 are on the same row. **Disclaimer: Testing revealed this will only work if PN/Item and QTY are both unique. If not, you will have to resort to a macro solution.**

The value you want to return is to the left of the columns you are looking up so you can't use `VLOOKUP` to return the value you want. The only option is to use `INDEX(array, row_num, [column_num])` using row_num returned by one of your `MATCH` formula:

`=INDEX('[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$U:$U, MATCH(V1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,0))`

Now we can put it all together in H1:

`=IF(AND(
    IF(ISNA(MATCH(V1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,0)),FALSE,TRUE),
    IF(ISNA(MATCH(K1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$X:$X,0)), FALSE, TRUE)),
 IF(MATCH(V1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,0)
=MATCH(K1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$X:$X,0),
    INDEX('[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$U:$U,
    MATCH(V1,'[HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls]Inbound'!$W:$W,0)),""),"")`

Indentation added to make it a bit easier to read.

Tried and tested by creating a HW inbound shipment info 21 Oct (2).xls workbook with an Inbound sheet having test data in columns U, W and X.